# L'extension de sens de « faire l'impasse » connote-t-elle un « risque » etc. ?

Tags: sens, locutions, déterminants, connotation, fréquence-utilisation

> Le constructeur suédois Volvo a reconfirmé son penchant vert en
> annonçant son intention de **faire l’impasse** sur les mécaniques
> entièrement à essence pour ses modèles 2023. ([LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/auto/guide-auto/2022-07-08/volvo/seulement-des-vehicules-hybrides-ou-electriques-au-canada.php))

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_l%E2%80%99impasse) dit « écarter ou ne pas traiter un sujet volontairement ». Donc « impasse » c'est 1730, d'abord un terme de jeu de carte (*faire l'*) et ensuite l'argot scolaire (1936) « ne pas réviser la totalité des ses cours avant un examen » et ensuite des extensions de sens ; on dit aussi « [faire une impasse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/impasse/41808#156555) ». (DHLF/Rey).

Lequel de l'emploi avec le déterminant défini (l') ou indéfini (une) est le plus courant ? « Faire impasse » sans déterminant est-il acceptable (comme *faire abstraction de*) ? Dans la citation, quel est le sens : est-ce simplement *éviter/faire abstraction* ou y a-t-il une connotation de *risque* (prendre le risque de faire abstraction de) ?

Comment: J'ai pas demandé mais si on sait depuis quand ça signifie _faire abstraction_ ou si on peut dire si c'est très récent ou très peu après 1936 ça m'intéresse de savoir. J'apprends l'expression dans l'article...

Comment: Ouais, le _inpasse_ (sic) était voulu dans le sens que c'était la graphie originale dixit DHLF mais je sais pas trop comment présenter ça. C'est pas un détail important.

Comment: Ah oui, j'avais pourtant cherché une première fois cette *inpasse* mais sans succès. On la trouve bien en 1730 et 1776, mais aussi *impasse* en 1742, qui a repris et corrigé le premier. Les *N* devant *P* n'étant pas légion en français, *embo**np**oint*, *perlimpi**np**in* et *ranta**np**lan* :-), je me demande s'il ne s'agissait quand même pas d'une simple coquille.

Comment: Je ne connaissais personnellement pas l'emploi indéfini dans le contexte d'un examen (dans celui d'un jeu de cartes oui)... merci !

Answer (score 3):

***Faire l'impasse sur** [...]* est beaucoup plus courant. On emploie ***une*** surtout si on ne précise pas sur quoi l'impasse a été faite.

L'expression est ancienne lorsqu'elle se réfère aux jeux de cartes, au [piquet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piquet_(jeu_de_cartes)), à l'[hombre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hombre_(jeu)) et ses variants puis plus tard au bridge.

[image]

Source: *Les jeux de quadrille et de piquet. Avec le médiateur*, 1742

Je n'ai jamais entendu *faire impasse*.

Une part de risque est pour moi associée au fait de faire une impasse. ***Faire une impasse***/***faire l'impasse sur [...]*** est toujours assimilé à un pari (*a gamble*), ce que ***faire abstraction*** n'exprime pas.

Answer (score 0):

Et ajouter à ce que @jiliagre a dit, je répondrai à la partie de votre question cherchant à savoir si le terme "impasse" a une connotation de risque,  je dirai oui, il a même une connotation dangereuse d'autant plus que le terme "impasse" signifie "Rue sans issue". Je suis tomber dans une "impasse" signifie que je suis tombé sur "une rue sans issue".
Dans ce même ordre d'idées, l'annonce que "*Le constructeur suédois Volvo a reconfirmé son penchant vert en annonçant son intention de faire l’impasse sur les mécaniques entièrement à essence...*" implique que Volvo a conscience de la dangerosité de sa decision mais choisit de faire abstraction de ce risque, soit pour n'avoir pas mesurer la réelle portée de ce risque, soit en jugeant que le jeu en vaut la chandelle. Dans les deux cas il y'a conscience d'un risque, et une ostracisation de ce risque à tort ou à raison.